# SSIS package data flow tasks report

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, etl

We have many SSIS packages that move, import, export around large amount of data. What is the best way to get alerts or notifications if expected amount of data is not processed? or How to get daily report on how different SSIS packages are functioning. Is there a way to write/use a custom component and simply plug it in to SSIS packages instead of writing custom component for each package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For your first question, we use user variables in SSIS to log the
   number of rows processed by each step along with the package name
   and execution id.  You can then run reports on the history table,
   and if any of the executions have a large variance in the rowcounts
   processed, you can trigger an event.
2. Yes.  See [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/developing-a-custom-ssis-source-component/), or in the alternative, google "custom ssis
   component tutorial".